# How to suppress the function to return "Null" in R?

Tags: r, return

I wrote a R function to return rows satisfying specific requirements, but I got problem with output format.

For example, return rows with certain values:

```
xx.1 <- data.frame(aa= 1:5, bb = c("AA","BB","CC","DD","EE"))
xx.2 <- c("AA","DD")
ff_in <- function(x,y){
  if (toupper(x[2]) %in% y) {return(x)}
}
apply(xx.1,1,ff_in,xx.2)
```

However, the output looks like :

```
[[1]]
aa   bb 
"1" "AA" 

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
NULL

[[4]]
aa   bb 
"4" "DD" 

[[5]]
NULL
```

How to suppress R return null, and return something likes this?

```
aa bb
"1" "AA" 
"4" "DD"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to just do:

```
xx.1[ toupper(xx.1[[2]]) %in% xx.2 , ]
```

If you needed it in a function, I'm sure this would be faster and would also not have the undesirable side-effect of coercion of a dataframe to a character matrix.

```
exncol <- function(df, coln, choices) df[ toupper(df[[coln]]) %in% choices , ]
exncol(xx.1, 2, xx.2)
  aa bb
1  1 AA
4  4 DD
```

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
do.call(rbind,apply(xx.1,1,ff_in,xx.2))
```

?  That combines all the results row-by-row; `rbind`ing a `NULL` vector has no effect.

Comment: But does it work for `File_Not_Found` ?   (bad joke from other techie forums)

Comment: Never thought of  do.call before, Thanks!